# Is there a method to fill the blanks between each Chinese characters? And how to force LaTeX to begin a new line when typsetting Chinese?

Tags: beamer, cjk

Here is my source code,I use CJK to typset Chinese,I am an absolute beginner,and I am working hard to study latex and CJK typseting skill.I want to fill the blank with the next line first charactors.I want to display the text even more small than the effect made by \small .Any advice will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
\title{moumou专题}
\author{author}
\institute{moumou@gmail.com}
\date{2013-07-19}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello Title!}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\small
在平面直角坐标系$xoy$中,点B与点$A(-1,1)$关于原点O对称,P是动点,且直线AP与BP的斜率之积等于$-\dfrac{1}{3}$.\\
(I)求动点P的轨迹方程;\\
(II)设直线AP和BP分别与直线x=3交于点M,N,问:是否存在点P使得$\bigtriangleup{PAB}$与$\bigtriangleup{PMN}$ 的面积相等?若存在,求出点P的坐标;若不存在,说明理由.
\end{frame}
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

A screeshot also attached.I want to modify the red-black colored field.

[image: the screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as Ellett has pointed out, it is better to use `enumerate` in this case.

Secondly, you can use the following commands to control font size:
[image]

This image comes from [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX), which serves as a great introduction to LaTeX. Here is the [PDF version](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/LaTeX.pdf).

Now, back to your main issue. Mixing western and CJK characters will often cause line-breaking problem. A lazy fix is simply insert `\\` after `直线` and `$\bigtriangleup{PAB}$$` (`$\bigtriangleup\text{PMN}$` would be better, just saying) so it can produce your desired results. For better alignment, however, I suggest you use [xeCJK](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xecjk) (or [ctex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctex)) package, which handles spacing and line-breaking better in my opinion. [Here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/xetex/latex/xecjk/xeCJK.pdf) is the package document, which comes in both Chinese and English.

Finally, I modified your code a little bit using `xeCJK`, see if you like the result:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ctex}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}

\title{moumou专题}
\author{author}
\institute{moumou@gmail.com}
\date{2013-07-19}

\begin{frame}[t]
\footnotesize
在平面直角坐标系$xoy$中,点B与点$\text{A}(-1,1)$关于原点O对称,P是动点,且直线AP与BP的斜率之积等于$-\dfrac{1}{3}$.\\
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 求动点P的轨迹方程;
    \item 设直线AP和BP分别与直线$x=3$交于点M,N,问:是否存在点P使得$\bigtriangleup\text{PAB}$与$\bigtriangleup\text{PMN}$的面积相等?若存在,求出点P的坐标;若不存在,说明理由.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help.Your solution is pretty good!I will take a note of it.Here comes some questions,Is there a method to set the main question display with no indent?And How can I set the blank between lines much more narrow?If I want to change from CJK to xeCJK or ctex ,should I make some changes about my recent latex?(which I installed all texlive2012,choose the symbol link,never set the path,it is a very traight installation,but works).

Comment: I really want to change my typseting method to xecjk or ctex,but maybe there are some settings I have not done to my Ubuntu 12.04,texlive2012,beacause I copied the code ,tried pdflatex latex xelatex,finally failed,not long ago,I started searching the internet to study latex,I saw lots of code with ctex but few about xecjk.I change some if I can to CJK,which can works but looks not so beautiful.Please give me some advice to help me be able to use xecjk and ctex.Thanks.

Comment: Hi. You're encouraged to post follow up question as a new question. As comment is usually not good for long answer. See: [Follow up questions to answered thread](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3597/follow-up-questions-to-answered-thread). In addition, if you find some answer to your question satisfying. Please consider mark it as accepted answer. See: [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)

Comment: Now back to your question. Indentation and space between lines can usually be adjusted by using `\setlength{\parindent}{0}` and `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}` command in preamble, respectively. For more detail, see [Lengths](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths). However, do notice that `ctex` package has its own customized setting, so `\setlength` command won't work in preamble. Use `\usepackage[noindent]{ctex}` instead. For more detail, see [ctex Package doc­u­men­ta­tion](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctex).

Comment: Also, it seems that you didn't provide enough information aabout why you can't use `xeCJK`. So please consider describe it more thoroughly in a new post.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I am new to stackoverflow.com.I will read the docs,if I can not fix the problem,I will post it.

Answer (score 2):

There are different font sizes you can choose from (in order from larger to smaller)

```
\normalsize
\small
\footnotesize
\scriptsize
\tiny
```

Also, you can use the enumerate environment for your list:

In the preamble of your document put:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

And then in the body of the text you can create your list as follows:

```
\begin{frame}[t] 
\footnotesize 在平面直角坐标系$xoy$中,点B与点$A(-1,1)$关于原点O对称,P是动点,且直
线AP与BP的斜率之积等于$-\dfrac{1}{3}$.\ 
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item 求动点P的轨迹方程;\ 
\item 设直线AP和BP分别与直线x=3交于点M,N,问:
\end{enumerate}
是否存在点P使得$\bigtriangleup{PAB}$与$\bigtriangleup{PMN}$ 的面积相等?若存在,求出点P的坐标;若不存在,说明理由. 
\end{frame}
```

Comment: The font size item footnotesize can help me get my expect effect.Enumitem package also very helpful,thanks.